# Swift 3 - Filter and sort array of dictionaries, by dictionary values, with values from array

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I am trying to implement the following behavior in an elegant way:

> Reorder `users` by the id in `userIds` and filter out all `user`s whose id isn't in `userIds`

Trying to do it the "Swifty way":

```
var users = [["id": 3, "stuff": 2, "test": 3], ["id": 2, "stuff": 2, "test": 3], ["id": 1, "stuff": 2, "test": 3]]
var userIds = [1, 2, 3]

userIds.map({ userId in users[users.index(where: { $0["id"] == userId })!] })
```

produces the expected result for the reordering and filtering. But the code crashes when `userIds` contains an id that doesn't belong to a `user` in `users` (e.g. `4`) thanks to the force-unwrap.

What am I missing to make it work without crashing?

Comment: You should consider using a custom data type for your users rather than a `Dictionary`, seeing as the keys in your dictionaries seems static. Dictionaries should not be used as a substitute for collections of custom light-weight types (which they, based on many questions here on SO, seemingly are ...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var users = [
    ["id": 3, "stuff": 2, "test": 3],
    ["id": 2, "stuff": 2, "test": 3],
    ["id": 1, "stuff": 2, "test": 3]
]
var userIds = [2, 1, 3]

let filteredUsers = userIds.flatMap { id in
    users.first { $0["id"] == id }
}
print(filteredUsers)
```

Answer (score 5):

The following works:

```
let m = userIds.flatMap { userId in users.filter { $0["id"] == userId }.first }
```

It `filter`s to find the correct member and then "flat"s the resulting array, removing the empty optionals.

Comment: I sensed a flatmap would do a great job but couldn't figure it out (pretty new to this). Works well, thanks !

Comment: You can improve this by using `first` instead of `filter`. It's presumably more efficient because of short-circuiting (i.e. `first` would stop searching once it finds the a match, whereas `filter` would not), and also makes for slightly shorter code.

Comment: @paulvs I know, that is why I already upvoted the second answer which basically does exactly that.

Comment: Switching accepted answer for the sake of optimization :)

Answer (score 0):

This will be useful when you have dublicate **ID**

```
var users = [["id": 1, "stuff": 4, "test": 5],["id": 3, "stuff": 2, "test": 3], ["id": 2, "stuff": 2, "test": 3], ["id": 1, "stuff": 2, "test": 3]]
    var userIds = [1, 2, 3]

        let filter = userIds.map {
            id in
            users.filter {
                $0["id"] == id
            }
        }

        print(filter)
```